# CursorAdapter not calling newView or bindView android

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter

I am trying to display images from a database in a `GridView` within a `Fragment`. For some reason, the CursorAdapter's `newView()` or `bindView()` method is not getting called. Here is my code:

GridImageAdapter.java class:

```
public class GridImageAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    private static String TAG = "Image_Debug";

    private Context mContext;
    private int count;
    private String columnname;

    public GridImageAdapter(Context context,Cursor cursor,int flag){
        super(context,cursor,flag);
        this.mContext = context;
        //this.columnname = columnname;
        Log.d(TAG, "calling grid imageadapter now");
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }


    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    /*@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ImageView image;
        ViewHolder holder;

        if(convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.media_view, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();  
            holder.image = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.media_image_id);    
            convertView.setTag(holder); 
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }   

           // holder.image.setImageBitmap((position).getBitmap());    

        return convertView;
    }*/

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        Log.d(TAG, "calling bind view");
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
        String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(WeatherImageDB.CLOUDY));
        Log.d(TAG, "string name in gridimageadapter is" + name);

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(name);

        Bitmap newbitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 120, 120, false);
        holder.image.setImageBitmap(newbitmap);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup container) {
        Log.d(TAG, "calling new view here");
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.media_view, container, false);

            holder.image = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.media_image_id);   
            view.setTag(holder);    

            return view;
    }
}

class ViewHolder {
   ImageView image;
   TextView item_name;
}
```

and from fragment:

```
public class PhotoFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

private static final int FRIENDS_LOADER = 0;

private static final int MYLOADER_LOADER = 1;

    TextView text;
    GridView grid;
    GridImageAdapter imageAdapter;

    PhotoDB dbadapter;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        dbadapter = new PhotosDB(getActivity().getApplicationContext()); //database class

        getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(FRIENDS_LOADER, null, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
            Bundle savedInstanceState){

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_tags, container, false);


    text = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.my_header_text_id);
    grid = (GridView)view.findViewById(R.id.my_tag_gridview_id);
    grid.setClipToPadding(false);

    imageAdapter = new GridImageAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), null, CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);
    grid.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {

        switch(id){
        case FRIENDS_LOADER:
                return new CustomCursorLoader(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), dbadapter,PhotoDB.FRIENDS);

        case MY_LOADER:

            return new CustomCursorLoader(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),dbadapter,PhotoDB.MYFOTOS);
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        if(loader.getId() == 0){
            imageAdapter.swapCursor(data);
                    text.setText("Friend Photos");  
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> args) {
        imageAdapter.swapCursor(null);

    }

    public static final class CustomCursorLoader extends SimpleCursorLoader {

        String columnname;
        PhotoDB dbadapter;

        public CustomCursorLoader(Context context, PhotoDB dbadapter, String columnname){
            super(context);
            this.dbadapter = dbadapter;
            this.columnname = columnname;
        }

        public CustomCursorLoader(Context context,String columnname){
            super(context);
            this.columnname = columnname;
        }

        @Override
        public Cursor loadInBackground() {
            Cursor cursor = null;
            dbadapter.open();

            Log.d(TAG, "retrieving tag from database now");
            cursor = dbadapter.retrieveTag(columnname);

            return cursor;
        }

    }

}
```

So, my question is, why is the `CursorAdapter` not calling the `newView()`/`bindView()` methods? I can't even get the logcat output on those methods, so I know it's not reaching there. Thank you.

Comment: Please any help!!.. am really struggling here for days now. NewView or BindView is just not getting called with everything i have tried :(

Comment: I think you solved this by now(in which case you should add an answer and accept it to answer the question), but you use the `count` variable which is initialized by default with `0`(you don't initialize it with anything else) so the adapter thinks it doesn't have any rows to show.

Answer (score 4):

Well, I know it's late -I hadn't found this post- , but I had the same problem (though I was just trying to do a To-Do List). I've spent the last three hour trying to figure out what the problem was and looking for possible solutions somewhere on the web.

Maybe it could help somebody else anyway, so I'll put it.

In my case what worked was this:

This is part of my Main Activity with the onCreate method:

```
public class TimeTrackerActivity extends Activity implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>
{
public static final int TIME_ENTRY_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
public static final int TIME_EDIT_REQUEST_CODE = 2;

private TimeTrackerAdapterDB adapter;
private TimeTrackerDatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
private ListView listView;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    //Database Helper
    databaseHelper = new TimeTrackerDatabaseHelper(this);
    //ListView that wasn't showing anything -before solving it-
    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.times_list);
    //A private method I made for adding a listener to the ListView
    setListViewListener(listView);

    this.getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
}
```

... and moving down to the LoaderCallbacks methods:

```
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(this, 
            TimeTrackerContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

    return loader;
}

public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
            // I'm initializing my custom adapter here because it requires a cursor
    if (adapter == null)
        adapter = new TimeTrackerAdapterDB(this, cursor);
    else
        adapter.swapCursor(cursor);

    //THIS IS WHAT SOLVED IT!
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

So, in my case, the reason it wasn't working was because the adapter wasn't being set to the ListView, so my list didn't show anything and the methods newView() and bindView() never got called before.

Maybe it could work by setting the adapter to the GridView on your onLoadFinished, once the cursor load has been made.

Don't know if it will solve your problem or anyone else's but it worked for me. 
Hope it helps.

Comment: I had the same issue and the problem is that you call setAdapter to soon in the lifecycle. You need to call setAdapter in the onViewCreated (or later). Doing it this way you can take out all code except swapCursor in the onLoadFinished method.

Answer (score 2):

Try to change your code in this format it should work as you want.

```
 class GridImageAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
            LayoutInflater mInflater; 
            SimpleDateFormat sdf; 

            GridImageAdapter (Context context, Cursor cursor)
            {
                super(context, cursor);
                mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            }

            @Override
            public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent)
            {
                return mInflater.inflate(R.layout.yourxml, parent, false);
            }

           @Override
            public void bindView(View row, Context context, Cursor cursor)
            {
                ImageView expensesdate = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.dateWorked); 
                        You can Assign your image with this imageview.

            } 
        }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Tried your code. it still not working. i don't really understand why this is happening. :(

Answer (score 0):

I'v got this problem too, I solved it in this way, you can try it.
In your fragment,change this line:

```
getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(FRIENDS_LOADER, null, this);
```

to

```
getLoaderManager().initLoader(FRIENDS_LOADER, null, HomeFragment.this).forceLoad();
```

The former doesn't work because it make the Activity as context, so the Fragment won't be notified.